# Are falling objects harder to push compared to objects at rest

Tags: forces, acceleration, everyday-life, free-fall, inertia

While an object is still in the air falling under the influence of gravity, does it take greater force to push or steer it to the side compared to when the object is in a state of rest?

Comment: What do you think? Typically it's useful to know the what the question creator's current understanding and knowledge is so that we can best help, and to see how they've attempted to come to a solution, even if they haven't been successful.

Comment: What is your intuition about this?  It seems that you can't decide between "it does" and "it doesn't".  Why do you think it might, and why do you think that it might not?  If we know what you are thinking, we might be able to give you an insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you might find falling objects harder to push, *if* you factor in the drag force. Initially, before you apply any force, the direction of the velocity is1 downwards ($\downarrow$) and the corresponding drag force acts upward ($\uparrow$), because almost all the drag forces experienced in daily life can be written as

$$\mathbf F_{\text{drag}}=-g(|\mathbf v|) \mathbf{\hat v}$$

where $g(|\mathbf v|)$ is a scalar positive function of $|\mathbf v|$ and $\mathbf{\hat v}$ is the direction of velocity vector.

Now once you start applying the force, the body starts accelerating in the horizontal direction ($\rightarrow$) and thus gains a velocity in the horizontal direction. But as this happens, the drag force also develops a horizontal component in the opposite direction to the horizontal velocity ($\leftarrow$). This opposes your force and reduces the effect of your force. Thus you might feel harder to push a falling object

Practically, the time taken by any object to fall from reasonable heights is quite samll to notcics such a difficulty in pushing the object sideways. Moreover, a stationary object, most probably on the ground, will be acted upon by friction if we try to push it. The friction is very commonly felt and is definitely much stronger than air drag in everyday life cases. If you were talking about pushing on a frictionless surface, then that is actually easier than pushing against air drag.

<sub>**Note:** Do see the comments below this answer, where some common questions regarding the validity of my answer have been answered.</sub>

Comment: Drag is proportional to velocity, which can be split into horizontal and vertical components. The object's horizontal velocity is the same whether the object is falling vertically or not, so drag in the horizontal direction is completely unaffected. There is no difference whatsoever in the horizontal forces at play whether the object is falling or not. If the horizontal force introduces horizontal drag for a falling object, it will do the exact same for the same object on the ground. The fact that the falling object has higher vertical velocity does not result in greater horizontal drag.

Comment: @NuclearWang The drag is **not** always proportional to the velocity. In fact, most of the times it's proportional to the velocity squared. And when it's proportional to $v^2$, the expression for drag force becomes $v^2\sin \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle that the velocity vector makes with the vertical. Now since the horizontal velocity $v_h=v\sin\theta$, thus we can write, $F_{\text{horizontal drag}}=vv_h$. But in the block-on-ground case, the horizontal drag would've been $v_h ^2$. Now since $v>v_h$, thus drag force while falling is greater than the drag force while on ground.

Comment: I think that justifies taking back your downvote, if you wish to do so.

Answer (score 2):

As Galileo discovered some 400 years ago, a body's horizontal motion is independent of the vertical motion. A given resultant horizontal force acting on a falling body will give it the same horizontal acceleration (while the force is acting) as if the body had no vertical motion.

Answer (score 0):

Newton's second law is a vector equation $$\mathbf F=m\mathbf a$$

With two dimensional motion this gives us two equations

$$F_x=ma_x$$
$$F_y=ma_y$$

Therefore, the only way the scenario you propose can happen is if there is some horizontal force that depends on the vertical velocity $\mathbf f=f(v_y)\,\hat x$. For falling objects I don't think this is the case, even if you do consider air resistance. Therefore, I would say no, what you are asking about will not happen.

Comment: Will friction play any role that might cause such effects?